# SQL - how to get related values from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is based on userid which contains user favorite images

I have another table which contains the user name and user id of users

I want to run a query where i insert a name into a query, it then retrieves the userid and uses this userid to search the table of favorites returning the username and the images selected

I'm quite new to SQL so appreciate any help

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `atabl_users` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  'user to input value' 
LIMIT 0 , 30


SELECT * 
FROM  `atabl_joomgallery_users` 
WHERE  `uid` =17
ORDER BY  `azc6a_joomgallery_users`.`uid` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Please add structure (list of columns) of the atabl_users table to your question

Comment: users table has the following : 
id 
name
username
email

The joomgallery table has the following
 
uid
uuserid
piclist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use JOIN to combine your queries

```
SELECT j.* 
FROM  atabl_joomgallery_users j
JOIN atabl_users u ON u.id = j.uuserid
WHERE u.name LIKE ?
```

Note that LIKE might return several users so if you get a unique user name as input value you can change the where clause to

```
WHERE u.name = ?
```

Comment: i get this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: You need to replace ? with a user name (the string you get as input) for example 'john'

Comment: i still get error 1054 - Unknown column 'au.uid' in 'on clause': SELECT * FROM atabl_users au INNER JOIN atabl_joomgallery_users aju ON au.uid = aju.uid WHERE au.name LIKE "fred" AND aju.uid = 17 LIMIT 30

Comment: That comment isn't for me, is it? Anyway use single not double quotes around text strings. Also what is the name of the user id column in atabl_users?

Comment: thanks for the help, i need to input the user name and from this user name i need to  get the user id and pass this into the table which contains the favorites this will then be used to retrieve the users favorites from the favorites table which users userid .

Comment: Yes I know but what is the name of that column (user id) in the atabl_users? In my code I assumed uid but maybe that is not correct, apart from that my code should do what you want.

Comment: the name of the user id in user  tables is id  , i tried the below and know Fred has fovrites but it reurns nothing now?                                                 
SELECT * 
FROM  atable_joomgallery_users j
JOIN atable_users u ON u.id = j.uid
WHERE u.name LIKE 'Fred'

Comment: it seems that user id is causing the issue. the two tables i need to link are
users and joomgallery.

Users table has the following columns
id, name and email

the joomgallery table users the userid from the users table BUT calls it
uuserid! these are the 2 user ids that need to be linked

Comment: that worked however i need to enter in the exact name , how do i search for queries which match part of the input eg WHERE u.name LIKE 'r' returns all names with r?

Comment: You use a % sign at the start and/or end of the string to filter on, 'r%' will give you all names starting with r for instance or 'Fred%' will return both Fred and Fredrick

Answer (score 0):

If you are requiring all information from two tables, you require an ID that they both share, so that they can be linked (joined) together.

Based on the information you provided, I'm assuming that both tables contain the value "uid" as the user id.

As such, the following query should be used :

"SELECT * FROM atabl_users au INNER JOIN atabl_joomgallery_users aju ON au.uid = aju.uid WHERE au.name LIKE ? AND aju.uid = 17 LIMIT 30"

I've removed the ORDER BY, as you would need a different one. There is no use in ordering by uid if you've specified it as 17.

To explain, we are asking to get all information * from table atable_users, then we're assigning it a shorthand value of au, to make it easier to read later on. We're then joining this table set with another table, based on the two unique values. Then we can refine our search using our WHERE values, and then lastly LIMIT the result set by 30.

Comment: I tried but got this error? #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM atable_users au INNER JOIN atable___joomgallery_users aju ON au.uid ' at line 1

Comment: @itye1970 I made a spelling error in your table name, and you can see it in the error of the comment you posted. I've amended it now.

Comment: i get this error now #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND aju.uid = 17 LIMIT 30"' at line 1

Comment: You have to replace "?" with whatever you were going to input with 'user to input value'. Try replacing ? with a default value that you know exists.